# Что озаначает "RUN set -ex" в Dockerfile?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

Всем привет! Помогите)
Не могу понять строку в Dockerfile "**RUN set -ex**"

Что делает эта команда?

[image: Dockerfile целиком]

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно!